# Is worth starting with Moles in VS2010 right now?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, moles, microsoft-fakes

We are considering starting to use Moles as we found ourselves creating a lot of Facades here and there.

Then I read somewhere than Fakes is replacing Moles in VS2012 and that it requires changes to move from one infrastructure to the new one.

My question is, is it worth starting with Moles when we now that we will need to port the tests from one framework to the new one? Is the porting work big enough to continue using Facades until we move to VS2012 and we can start using Fakes?

Answer (score 4):

I would not make too much effort on Moles if you are moving to VS 2012 and intend to use fakes. There is enough difference to mean you will be doing a good deal of work.

There is some notes on my blog http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2012/03/23/Now-that-VS11-has-a-fake-library-do-I-still-need-Typemock-Isolator-to-fake-out-SharePoint.aspx

But the BEST place to look for details how the differences between moles/fakes and other frameworks can be found in the ALM rangers guide on the subject http://vsartesttoolingguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/102290

Comment: Remember Fakes is only available in VS 2012 Premium (w Update 2) and VS 2012 Ultimate.  If you are not going to use one of those versions then you will have no choice to look at other tools.